# Basic Sorting / Order Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

Trying to implement and form a very simple algorithm. This algorithm takes in a sequence of letters or numbers. It first creates an array (list) out of each character or digit. Then it checks each individual character compared with the following character in the sequence. If the two are equal, it removes the character from the array.

For example the input: 12223344112233 or AAAABBBCCCDDAAABB

And the output should be: 1234123 or ABCDAB

I believe the issue stems from the fact I created a counter and increment each loop. I use this counter for my comparison using the counter as an index marker in the array. Although, each time I remove an item from the array it changes the index while the counter increases.

Here is the code I have:

```
def sort(i):
    iter = list(i)
    counter = 0
    for item in iter:
        if  item == iter[counter + 1]:
            del iter[counter]
        counter = counter + 1
    return iter
```

Comment: Iterate backwards

Comment: `del iter[counter]` changes the list being iterated. Since the rest of the array has now moved down one position, what used to be in slot `iter[counter + 1]` is skipped in the next round of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

You're iterating over the same list that you are deleting from. That usually causes behaviour that you would not expect. Make a copy of the list & iterate over that.

However, there is a simpler solution: Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
import itertools

def sort(i):
    return [x for x, _ in itertools.groupby(list(i))]


print(sort('12223344112233'))
```

Output:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 2):

A few alternatives, all using `s = 'AAAABBBCCCDDAAABB'` as setup:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(.)\1+', r'\1', s)
'ABCDAB'
```

```
>>> p = None
>>> [c for c in s if p != (p := c)]
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']
```

```
>>> [c for c, p in zip(s, [None] + list(s)) if c != p]
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']
```

```
>>> [c for i, c in enumerate(s) if not s.endswith(c, None, i)]
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']
```

Answer (score -1):

The other answers a good. This one iterates over the list in reverse to prevent skipping items, and uses the look ahead type algorithm OP described. Quick note OP this really isn't a sorting algorithm.

```py
def sort(input_str: str) -> str:
    as_list = list(input_str)
    for idx in range(len(as_list), 0, -1)):
        if item == as_list[idx-1]:
            del as_list[idx]
    return ''.join(as_list)
```